# What does pyinstaller do with "builtins.help"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a simple Python interactive console application using PyInstaller.

I would like the Python help() to be available, but it seems that PyInstaller somehow changes the contents of `builtins` and removes help.

Here is a simple script that opens a Python window. When I run this script directly in a Windows Command Prompt, I can access `help()` from the interactive session.

```
import code
        
code.InteractiveConsole().interact()
```

However, if I build an executable by

`PyInstaller test.py`

and run it, `help` is not available. And when I look at the contents of `builtins` I see that it is not included.

I am on Windows 10, using the latest Python 3.8 release.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Nico's suggestion below, the following code restores builtins `quit()`, `exit()`, and `copyright()` functions, which were removed by pyinstaller.

```
import code

import builtins
if not hasattr(builtins,'help'):
    import _sitebuiltins

    if os.sep == '\\':
        eof = 'Ctrl-Z plus Return'
    else:
        eof = 'Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF)'

    builtins.quit = _sitebuiltins.Quitter('quit', eof)
    builtins.exit = _sitebuiltins.Quitter('exit', eof)
        
    builtins.help = _sitebuiltins._Helper()

    builtins.copyright = _sitebuiltins._Printer("copyright", sys.copyright)   
    
code.InteractiveConsole().interact()
```

Comment: If the answer helped, it is good practice to not only to accept it but also to upvote it and other users' useful answers. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fake *site.py* that PyInstaller uses - it also breaks the quit() and license function in the interactive shell. You need to change it a bit, adding the following code at the end (borrowed from the cPython 3.7 sources):

```
import os
import sys
import builtins
import _sitebuiltins


def setquit():
    """Define new builtins 'quit' and 'exit'.
    These are objects which make the interpreter exit when called.
    The repr of each object contains a hint at how it works.
    """
    if os.sep == '\\':
        eof = 'Ctrl-Z plus Return'
    else:
        eof = 'Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF)'

    builtins.quit = _sitebuiltins.Quitter('quit', eof)
    builtins.exit = _sitebuiltins.Quitter('exit', eof)


def sethelper():
    builtins.help = _sitebuiltins._Helper()

def main():
    """Add standard site-specific directories to the module search path.
    This function is called automatically when this module is imported,
    unless the python interpreter was started with the -S flag.
    """   
    setquit()
    sethelper()    


main()
```

I use these changes for buiding web2py / py4web binaries with a working interactive shell (see my github repositories if needed).

Comment: It usually a good practice to avoid adding hyperlinks to your answer if you can just add the relevant part of code here.

Comment: You're right, I don't do it normally. Basically, you should add to the fake site,py from PyInstaller the relevant functions from the same module on the official python.org program.

Comment: Still, you should place the relevant part of code here, if you want to increase your chances of having your answer accepted and avoid downvotes.

Comment: I've followed your suggestions by editing the original post ;-)